# How to design that the PutEmail Processor is Trigger by all Processor with failure flowfile?

Tags: apache-nifi

As the title,there are many processor,and then i want to get email by the PUTEMAIL processor if any one processor is fail.

I try to connect every processor with the PUTEMAIL processor.Too trouble!
My target is to get tips about error and modify processor as soon as possible.Any help is appreciate!!!

Comment: Think about using smtpappender in logback.xml to send all errors by email. http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: @daggett Thanks.My target is to get tips about error and modify processor as soon as possible.Don't need detail error message.Any other suggestion?